# Vim: Splitting a list onto new lines

Tags: vim, replace

Is there a Vim command (I'm guessing a search and replace?) that can change:

```
listThing(["fish", "monkey", "cat", "penguin"])
```

into:

```
listThing([
    "fish",
    "monkey",
    "cat",
    "penguin"
])
```

It's not just adding a newline and tab after a comma, as the first and last line also need to be separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing what else might be in your file that this could match a simple approach would be:

```
:1,$s/\("[^ ,]*"\|\])\)/\r    \1/g
```

Which will get you:

```
listThing([
    "fish",
    "monkey",
    "cat",
    "penguin"
    ])
```

**EDIT:** As I stated above but will re-emphasize: how well this works for you might depend upon other similar constructs in your file. Other options would be using the plugin that Ingo suggested, or writing a separate script in `awk`, `perl`, or `<insert-favorite-script-language-here>`.

Answer (score 2):

For a particular case, a `:substitute` command proposed by @lurker's answer can be sufficient. Unfortunately, with many programming languages, there can be nesting of structures, and it's difficult to process all of these correctly. Therefore, for a robust, "don't make me think" solution, I think you need a plugin. Though I haven't tried it yet, the [argwrap plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5062) offers this.

Comment: Very useful plugin. Good call.

Comment: I totally agree with the narrow scope of my solution (thus my lame caveat, *Not knowing what else might be in your file that this could match...*). :)